# Why are exceptions within a Python generator not caught?

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator

I have the following experimental code whose function is similar to the `zip` built-in. What it tries to do should have been simple and clear, trying to return the zipped tuples one at a time until an `IndexError` occurs when we stop the generator.

```
def my_zip(*args):
    i = 0
    while True:
        try:
            yield (arg[i] for arg in args)
        except IndexError:
            raise StopIteration
        i += 1
```

However, when I tried to execute the following code, the `IndexError` was not caught but instead thrown by the generator:

```
gen = my_zip([1,2], ['a','b'])
print(list(next(gen)))
print(list(next(gen)))
print(list(next(gen)))


IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
I:\Software\WinPython-32bit-3.4.2.4\python-3.4.2\my\temp2.py in <module>()
     12 print(list(next(gen)))
     13 print(list(next(gen)))
---> 14 print(list(next(gen)))

I:\Software\WinPython-32bit-3.4.2.4\python-3.4.2\my\temp2.py in <genexpr>(.0)
      3     while True:
      4         try:
----> 5             yield (arg[i] for arg in args)
      6         except IndexError:
      7             raise StopIteration
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Why is this happening?

### Edit:

Thanks @thefourtheye for providing a nice explanation for what's happening above. Now another problem occurs when I execute:

```
list(my_zip([1,2], ['a','b']))
```

This line never returns and seems to hang the machine. What's happening now?

Comment: Roughly said, you try to do something like `def func():  try: return None except: pass`, if I properly understand how `yield` works.

Comment: @Riliam, but the code you provided would have caught the error like return 1 / 0.

Comment: Not related to your issue, but you should `return` instead of raising StopIteration - raising StopIteration explicitly within a generator [is deprecated and will change in the future](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0479/).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `yield` yields a generator object everytime and when the generators were created there was no problem at all. That is why `try...except` in `my_zip` is not catching anything. The third time when you executed it,

```
list(arg[2] for arg in args)
```

this is how it got reduced to (over simplified for our understanding) and now, observe carefully, *`list` is iterating the generator, not the actual `my_zip` generator*. Now, `list` calls `next` on the generator object and `arg[2]` is evaluated, only to find that `2` is not a valid index for `arg` (which is `[1, 2]` in this case), so `IndexError` is raised, and `list` fails to handle it (it has no reason to handle that anyway) and so it fails.

---

As per the edit,

```
list(my_zip([1,2], ['a','b']))
```

will be evaluated like this. First, `my_zip` will be called and that will give you a generator object. Then iterate it with `list`. It calls `next` on it, and it gets another generator object `list(arg[0] for arg in args)`. Since there is no exception or `return` encountered, it will call `next`, to get another generator object `list(arg[1] for arg in args)` and it keeps on iterating. Remember, the yielded generators are never iterated, so we ll never get the `IndexError`. That is why the code runs infinitely.

You can confirm this like this,

```
from itertools import islice
from pprint import pprint
pprint(list(islice(my_zip([1, 2], ["a", 'b']), 10)))
```

and you will get

```
[<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f4d0a709678>,
 <generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f4d0a7096c0>,
 <generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f4d0a7099d8>,
 <generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f4d0a709990>,
 <generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f4d0a7095a0>,
 <generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f4d0a709510>,
 <generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f4d0a7095e8>,
 <generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f4d0a71c708>,
 <generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f4d0a71c750>,
 <generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f4d0a71c798>]
```

So the code tries to build an infinite list of generator objects.

Comment: Thanks! @thefourtheye for the great explanation. Could you see my edit for another problem?

Comment: @VictorYan I addressed that now. Please check the updated answer.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! I now have a better understanding of how generators work.

Answer (score 2):

```
def my_zip(*args):
    i = 0
    while True:
        try:
            yield (arg[i] for arg in args)
        except IndexError:
            raise StopIteration
        i += 1
```

`IndexError` is not caught, because `(arg[i] for arg in args)` is a generator which is not executed immediately, but when you start iterating over it. And you iterate over it in another scope, when you call `list((arg[i] for arg in args))`:

```
# get the generator which yields another generator on each iteration
gen = my_zip([1,2], ['a','b'])
# get the second generator `(arg[i] for arg in args)` from the first one
# then iterate over it: list((arg[i] for arg in args))
print(list(next(gen)))
```

- On the first `list(next(gen))` `i` equals 0.
- On the second `list(next(gen))` `i` equals 1.
- On the third `list(next(gen))` `i` equals 2. And here you get `IndexError` -- in the outer scope. The line is treated as `list(arg[2] for arg in ([1,2], ['a','b']))`

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I'm not able to offer a coherent explanation regarding the failure to catch the exception, however, there's an easy way around it; use a for loop over the length of the shortest sequence:

```
def my_zip(*args):
    for i in range(min(len(arg) for arg in args)):
        yield (arg[i] for arg in args)

>>> gen = my_zip([1,2], ["a",'b','c'])
>>> print(list(next(gen)))
[1, 'a']
>>> print(list(next(gen)))
[2, 'b']
>>> print(list(next(gen)))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `yield (arg[i] for ...)` with the following.

```
for arg in args:
    yield arg[i]
```

*But* in case of numbers that causes an exception as `1[1]` makes no sense. I suggest replacing `arg[i]` just with `arg`.

Comment: I am trying to rebuild the built-in zip function, and your code doesn't do what's supposed to. And more importantly, I want to understand why my code doesn't work the way it should have. (I didn't downvote you.)